# Аналог FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure и FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender из wpf в AVALONIA UI?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Перевожу приложение под wpf в avalonia ui. В ходе переноса столкнулся с тем, чего нет в документации. В общем есть кусок кода из wpf:

```
public class BaseLabelElement : UIElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FontFamily", typeof(FontFamily), typeof(BaseLabelElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultFontFamily,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, FontFamilyPropertyChanged));

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Как добавить добиться поведения, соответствующего "new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(..,          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,..)"?
Также хочу добавить, что есть возможность в конструкторе добавить через методы AffectsMeasure("Список свойств зависимостей") и AffectsRender("Список свойств зависимостей") добавить флаги для данных свойств, **но они не рекомендованные**

Comment: Мне кажется, с таким вопросом лучше на английский StackOverflow сходить, там есть тег `avalonia` и его просматривают разработчики Авалонии, а здесь если только повезет, то кто-то ответит, потому что сама по себе Авалония пока не очень популярна.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AffectsRender <T> (AvaloniaProperty []) и AffectsMeasure <T> (AvaloniaProperty [])` в классе Visual. Эти методы должен вызываться в статическом конструкторе элемента управления с каждым свойством элемента управления, которое при изменении должно вызывать перерисовку. Это похоже на флаги FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsRender и AffectsMeasure в WPF.